# Cloud Based Automation Testing with Selenium WebDriver - Java

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, selenium2, performance, mobile

I am beginner in selenium webdriver (java), and wanted to know whether selenium webdriver can be used in cloud based application testing or not, if yes how to setup it (Searched over the net but didn't get particular solution).

Suppose, if selenium will support (Cloud) then is it good to use in cloud testing? instead of other tools specifically meant for cloud application testing.

As per my understanding we can do functionality and performance testing in the cloud, and  selenium is good for cross browsers, functionality...etc but not for load, stress, etc...

*If you think or as per your experience if selenium is not good/suitable for cloud based applications testing then which tool you want to suggest to me.*

Comment: What is cloud based testing? Do you test the cloud infrastructure or an application in the cloud. I think your question is a bit vague. Maybe you can describe your situation in more detail and what problems you run into and what are your goals.

Comment: I am working on SaaS applications and client is expecting me to get knowledge on cloud environment and testing the Application in the cloud. So I know only Selenium webdriver tool and do not know any other tool, even also dont know how to test or cloud environment. So i thought if selenium support then some how I can manage the tasks. And I have a 2 weeks of time to learn new tool also. This is the whole story. Goals: Learn new tool (If selenium not support for load, etc) and cloud environment knowledge (I will not get much time after getting assignments from client).

Answer (score 4):

Although i do not have much idea about it but i think you can give selenium grid a try. I read on seleniumhq.org that with selenium grid you can create a master slave architecture, where one master machine will control several slaves to send request to a common server. Maybe this can help solve your issue!

Answer (score 3):

Selenium is a tool to drive and verify behavior of web-applications, it should not matter where they are hosted. If you can reach the webserver running the application it can be local or hosted in the cloud, the application should behave the same.

If you want to test if the cloud setup can handle a certain load and find its bottlenecks I would look at a load testing tool like [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [FunkLoad](http://funkload.nuxeo.org/)

Comment: Above links are useful specially Jmeter (Up voted for the suggestion). Any tool (Open source) to do both functionality and performance?. And any free cloud environment is available to work around (Want to learn Load balancing, etc..).

Comment: I also want to know free/trail cloud environment and tool for both functional and performance.

Comment: Amazone offers a free tier for 12 months, but this includes only one node. http://aws.amazon.com/free/ Maybe you could setup a "private" cloud with virtual-machines to mimic a cloud env, most clouds are VMs, storage and a management tool anyways. You could use the cloud Selenium service of https://saucelabs.com/ to scale up the volume of the Selenium tests so that they feel like a performance test, but I think you should use the best tool for the job. And these types of tests are just different and need a different tool.