# Where can I find good tutorials for Cloud Environment, Automated Testing in Cloud and Tools

Tags: automated-testing, performance, test-automation-framework, browser-automation, mobile

I want to learn automation testing in cloud and I do not have knowledge or experience in cloud environment. I searched over the internet and found some blogs, steps, etc but I am not sure whether those are correct or not and which tool, etc (Totally confused).

I am new to this so not sure from where I need to start, I am very much sure from this forum I will get some help (Someone may working on the cloud).

As I have never used this environment, tools before, I would just like to know where I can find good tutorials for beginners?.

Which tool you prefer for me (Functional, Performance and Mobile applications)? (Open source and Paid).

Comment: Once look into this link http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9845/cloud-based-automation-testing-with-selenium-webdriver-java and refer @Niels van Reijmersdal comments you may get some idea on performance testing.

Comment: What you want actually?. Environment or tools?.

Comment: Environment setup (Trail/Free), tools (Functional, Performance and Mobile applications), and tutorials for beginners. **I am new to these so want to learn from basics**.

Comment: I appreciate that it's often hard to formulate specific questions as a beginner, but this is just too broad. What's your purpose for learning this stuff? That might help us to suggest good terms to search for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how testing in the cloud is different then testing on your local computer system.

The only thing the CLOUD delivers is a scalable type of infrastructure. If you need to test the scalability of the infrastructure, then search for "Scalability testing" and read blogs like [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/testing-the-limits-of-cloud-scalability-real-world-results/). Load testing mobile API's could be done with tools like [BlazeMeter](http://blazemeter.com/).

I think you need to find tools and tutorials which assist in testing different parts of the [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack).

- Functional testing of web-application
- Functional testing of mobile-application
- Load/Performance test of cloud infrastructure (IO, Database, Network, etc)
- API testing
- Setting up a cloud environment for testing (Ask your operations/devops team)

There is not a single resource that will explain all this knowledge from scratch and get you going. Therefor I think your question is way to broad.

Answer (score 1):

Few more notes on top of Neils Answer

**Test Environment Setup using Cloud Infrastructure**

- Load generation in cloud for on premises application
- Load generator on premises, application on cloud
- Both load generator and application both on cloud

**Load Testing**

- Flood IO - https://flood.io/
- LoadFocus - https://loadfocus.com/

**Security Testing**

- NTOSpider - http://www.ntobjectives.com/security-software/ntospider-application-security-scanner/
- Burp Proxy - http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html

Comment: Very nice, what is load balancing?. How to do it?.

Comment: Load balancing can be simple IP based / Request level/  sticky / non-sticky. You can try load balancers using Ngnix, Apache, Zen Loadbalancer, F5 load balancer.